# A metric defined in terms of the minimum distance to a subset of metric space

Tags: real-analysis

For a set $S$ in a metric space $(M,d)$ and $x \in M$, let

$$
d(x,S):=\inf_{s \in S}d(x,s)
$$

Show that the distance for points in the closure of a set is zero:

$$
d(x,S)=0 \Leftrightarrow x \in \bar{S}
$$

Comment: Did you manage to prove at least one implication? This is not much more than just the definitions...

Comment: @ Federico: The first term is definition of a metric but the second part is indeed a characteristic of a metric that we have defined.

Comment: $d(\,\cdot\,,S)$ is not a metric. It's just a function defined on $M$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x \in \bar{S}$ if and only if $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists s \in S$ such that $d(x,s)<\epsilon$.